# Edit button click get image name and display input file chosen using angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc

I want to be able to remove the "No file Chosen" to add **category.ImageName**  when i click edit button. added **[(ngModel)]="category.ImageName"** in the input but it is not working.

```
<div *ngIf="category.FileSource.length > 0; else customAvatar">
                                <input 
                                formControlName="File"
                                id="File" 
                                type="file" 
                                [value]="category.ImageName"
                                [(ngModel)]="category.ImageName"
                                (change)="onFileChange($event)"/>
                               
                                <img *ngIf="chnageeventimage==='true'; else changeAvatar" [src]="imageSrc || '../../../../../assets/images/camera.jpg'" style="height: 80px; width:80px">
                                <ng-template #changeAvatar>
                                <img  [src]="category.FileSource" style="width:80px; height:80px;" alt="User avatar" />
                            </ng-template>
```

Component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    debugger;
    const categoryID: string = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('categoryID');
     this.api.EditCategory(categoryID).subscribe(data =>{
      console.log(data);
      this.category = data;
    });
  }
```

out put

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can directly affect that text. I think you have to hide the whole element and apply your own component as a visual and proxy. Or, use a library like https://valor-software.com/ng2-file-upload/

Answer (score 1):

What you can make is hidden the input and customize an div or a button, like that:

```html
<div *ngIf="category.FileSource.length > 0; else customAvatar">
                                <input 
                                id='browse'
                                style='width:0px'
                                type="file" 
                                (change)="onFileChange($event)"/>
                                
                                <button onclick="browse.click()">Upload image</button>
                                
                                {{category.ImageName}}
                               
                                <img *ngIf="chnageeventimage==='true'; else changeAvatar" [src]="imageSrc || '../../../../../assets/images/camera.jpg'" style="height: 80px; width:80px">
                                <ng-template #changeAvatar>
                                <img  [src]="category.FileSource" style="width:80px; height:80px;" alt="User avatar" />
                            </ng-template>
```